# Enable hotlinking protection in nginx

Tags: nginx, configuration, hotlinking

ok, I've been trying this for a few months now and decided to give it another try.  Still giving me the same result.  My images are blocked if another domain tries to display one of the images on their website, but also mydomain.com (or my actual domain) is also blocked from loading any images.

Does ssl on the website has anything to do with this?  Did I put  location `~ \.(jpe?g|png|gif)$` at the wrong place?  I'm running nginx 1.19.0 on Windows.

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name mydomain www.mydomain.com;

        if ($host !~* ^www\.(.*)$) {
            return 301 https://www.$host$request_uri;
        }

        ssl_certificate         "D:/certificate.crt";
        ssl_certificate_key     "D:/private.key";
        ssl_session_cache       shared:SSL:1m;
        ssl_session_timeout     5m;
        ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
        ssl_protocols           TLSv1.2;


        root   "D:/MyWebsite";
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;


        location ~ \.php$ {
            root "D:/MyWebsite";
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        }

        location / {
            if ($request_uri ~* ".(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$") {
                # access_log off;
                expires 30d;
                add_header Pragma public;
                add_header Cache-Control "public";
                break;
            }
        }

        location ~ \.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ {
            valid_referers none blocked example.com *.example.com;

            if ($invalid_referer) {
                return 403;
            }
        }
}
```

I deleted the access log file for the domain in question and restarted nginx.  Tried to access the image file directly and could not load the image (was redirected to my 404 error page as set in nginx).  Here is the access log info:

```
server_name="example.com" host="www.example.com" server_port="443" server_addr="192.168.1.101" remote_addr="192.168.1.101" realip_remote_addr="192.168.1.101" remote_user="-" time_local="09/Jul/2020:20:17:37 -0600" server_protocol="HTTP/1.1" status="404" bytes_sent="1301" upstream_bytes_received="2208" body_bytes_sent="843" http_referer="-" http_user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" nginx_version="1.19.0" http_x_forwarded_for="-" http_x_header="-" query_string="-" uri="/Errors/404/index.php" http_method="GET" response_time="0.010" http_cookie="PHPSESSID=0000000009t654999999" request_time="0.010"
server_name="example.com" host="www.example.com" server_port="443" server_addr="192.168.1.101" remote_addr="192.168.1.101" realip_remote_addr="192.168.1.101" remote_user="-" time_local="09/Jul/2020:20:17:37 -0600" server_protocol="HTTP/1.1" status="200" bytes_sent="1092" upstream_bytes_received="-" body_bytes_sent="807" http_referer="https://www.example.com/content/somefolder/pix.jpg" http_user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" nginx_version="1.19.0" http_x_forwarded_for="-" http_x_header="-" query_string="random=1594347457" uri="/Libraries/Custom/Custom.js" http_method="GET" response_time="-" http_cookie="PHPSESSID=0000000009t654999999" request_time="0.000"
server_name="example.com" host="www.example.com" server_port="443" server_addr="192.168.1.101" remote_addr="192.168.1.101" realip_remote_addr="192.168.1.101" remote_user="-" time_local="09/Jul/2020:20:17:37 -0600" server_protocol="HTTP/1.1" status="200" bytes_sent="956" upstream_bytes_received="-" body_bytes_sent="671" http_referer="https://www.example.com/content/somefolder/pix.jpg" http_user_agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0" nginx_version="1.19.0" http_x_forwarded_for="-" http_x_header="-" query_string="random=1594347457" uri="/Global.js" http_method="GET" response_time="-" http_cookie="PHPSESSID=0000000009t654999999" request_time="0.000"
```

Comment: Everything is ok with your referers configuration, it should work as expected. Check the actual `Referer` header value in your access log, or add sample access log lines to your question. The third location block would prevent the cache control headers settings to be set on images. `jpe?g` is a regex that would match either `jpeg` or `jpg`, there is no need to duplicate it with `jpg`. And if you want to preserve cache control headers on the images, the whole thing should be done differently.

Comment: ok thanks.  I will take another look at this.  Both domains belongs to me and I'm not doing any referer spoofing or anything like that, so it is very weird the images are blocked even if they are hosted under the websites domain.